# How to make a post request with a custom token document ref with firebase firestore Rest API

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, http-post

Here is my code below, I'm trying to send a post request using Firebase Firestore Rest API. It works, but it generates a random ref id token that links it to the post data (fields) I sent, which makes it difficult to relate to.

I want to be able to link my post data with a custom id token.

```
final String customIdToken9 = 'customIdToken9'
String url = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myAppId/databases/(default)/documents/customers/$customIdToken9" 
const _body = {
"fields": {
    "androidNotificationToken": {
        "nullValue": null
    },
    "fullname": {
        "stringValue": "Custom"
    },
    "uid": {
        "stringValue": "$customIdToken9"
    },
    "admin": {
        "stringValue": ""
    },
    "email": {
        "stringValue": "customer1@gmail.com"
    },
    "photo": {
        "stringValue": ""
    },
    "coverPhoto": {
        "stringValue": ""
    },
    "bio": {
        "stringValue": ""
    },
    "role": {
        "stringValue": "user"
    },
    "mobile": {
        "stringValue": "092222"
    }
}
 }
   http.post(url, body = _body);
```

When I run this code above it returns

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Document parent name \"projects/MyAppId/databases/(default)/documents/customers\" lacks \"/\" at index 59.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

}

If I remove the customTokenId9, it works, but it generates a random token Id, which I don't want

```
String url = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myAppId/databases/(default)/documents/customers/" 

http.post(url, body = _body);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify your own document name, you need to add a query paramater called `documentId` to your URL request. Here's how it should look like on your code:

```
final String customIdToken9 = 'customIdToken9'
String url = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myAppId/databases/(default)/documents/customers?documentId=$customIdToken9" 
const _body = {
"fields": {
    "androidNotificationToken": {
        "nullValue": null
    },
    "fullname": {
        "stringValue": "Custom"
    },
    "uid": {
        "stringValue": "$customIdToken9"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

> The client-assigned document ID to use for creating a document. It is optional. If not specified, a random ID will automatically be assigned by the service.

Full description is stated in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument#http-request) and you'll see it in the Query Parameters section. You can also try to test out the API and expand it to see its `curl` equivalent.

Additionally, you can look up to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-uri-params) to understand how a query parameter works. It applies on any REST API's offered by Firebase.

Comment: nice, where did you find this cause I've checked on all the docs I couldn't find the soln

Comment: Hi @OkaforZuruoke, I've update my answer to further explain the details regarding the Query Parameters. I've also provided additional documentation link so you can also check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your variable `final String customIdToken` but you are using `$customIdToken9` it should be `$customIdToken`.

Comment: that was a typo in my detail implementation for stack overflow. It doesn’t matter. The main is how I can make a post request to firebase Firestore with a custom Id token document